# jqgrid .clearGridData() not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid 3.6.4. The following is a snippet of my code:

```
 jQuery("#lookupTable").clearGridData(true)
                          .addRowData('id',objArray5);
```

The problem that I am facing in firefox and chrome and not in IE, is that the grid is not getting cleared. Hence, every time the above mentioned code is called the data is being appended to the grid (whose id is 'lookupTable').

Could someone tell me why is the grid not getting cleared of its data?

Comment: Do you tried to use jqGrid 4.1.2? The version 3.6.4 is really a "retro" version. It's like a question about IE 5.5 - nobody has it more.

Comment: So, is this the problem only on version 3.6.4? Then why is it working for IE? Isn't .clearGridData() also a "retro" method? I will be upgrading soon, but for now, under certain circumstances, I can't.

Comment: I mean that I just have no version 3.6.4 and don't know whether the `clearGridData` have changed in all the years. Moreover it looks strange in your code that you use `'id'` string as the id for the new row. Are you sure that you don't use the string as the id for some another element on the page?

Comment: The 'id' is used to get the value of 'id' variable from the object. The value of this 'id' is then taken as the id for the new row. So, this does not matter. I checked the firebug output to verify this.

Comment: If you has variable with the name `id`, you should use `addRowData(id, objArray5)` and not `addRowData('id',objArray5)`. The last statement uses the string `'id'` and the row id and you can easy has id duplicates which are very dangerous. Another remark: I wrote many jqGrid examples, but I never need to use `clearGridData` and don't use `addRowData` since jqGrid 3.7.2. Probably you should describe how you fill the data. I suppose that you will be able to rewrite the code to have better performance and no problems which you described here.

Comment: I tried    addRowData(id, objArray5), but it gives error, saying "id" is undefined. I have four buttons which when clicked opens a modal dialog box containing data in a jqgrid. I am reusing the same dialog box and jqGrid for all the four buttons. Therefore, I needed to clear the grid and add new rows. The colModel is same for all.

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation say me not so much. The problem is mostly not what you *want to do*, but *what you really do*. Yo have a problem which you describes. You wrote before about "'id' variable", which seems not correct. So it would be more effective if you post your code instead of describing of what the code should do.  The problem is mostly **in the implementation** which one can see only from the code.

Answer (score 2):

I remember facing the same issue. I resolved it by reloading grid after clear and then adding the new data. This issue exists even in the recent 4.1.2v also.

```
   jQuery("#lookupTable").clearGridData(true).trigger("reloadGrid")
.addRowData('id',objArray5);
```

I hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: No effect. I am still facing the same problem. Works in IE but not in firefox and chrome.